# ¿Cómo hacer multiples comparaciones en un select en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Esto es lo que he intentado pero no me funciona:

```html
include("conexion.php");

$resultado1 = $conecta->query("SELECT campo1 FROM tabla1 WHERE id='respuestas'");
$filas1 = $resultado1->fetch_assoc();
$campo1 = $filas1['campo1'];
echo $campo1; 

$resultado2 = $conecta->query("SELECT campo2 FROM tabla2 WHERE id='pensamientos'");
while($filas2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2)) {
$campo2 = $filas2['campo2'];
echo $campo2;

$resultado3 = $conecta->query("SELECT campo3 FROM tabla3 WHERE id='libros'");
while($filas3 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado3)) {
$campo3 = $filas3['campo3'];
echo $campo3;
//la tabla está así:
//campo1 campo2 campo3 id 
//   x      x      x   respuestas
//   y      y      y   pensamientos
//   z      z      z   libros
```

Lo que quiero hacer son multiples consultas, aunque están en la misma tabla, tienen diferente id. ¿como puedo lograr esto?

> El resultado que me gustaria obrtener es: x, y, z.

Comment: ¿Quieres obtener todos los registros a la vez o solo los que coincidan con esos ids?

Comment: @BetaM solo los que coincidan con los ids

Comment: siempre vas a querer recuperar las mismas columnas o distintas?

Comment: @BetaM por el momento siempre las mismas columnas

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas estar construyendo un `SELECT` por cada registro o registros que deseas recuperar.

En estos casos te puedes apoyar de un filtro `WHERE IN` para que el selector obtenga todos los regitros que en su id tengan uno u otro identificador, de esta forma:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE identificador IN(valor1, valor2, ....., valorN);
```

Entonces para tu consulta podemos:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id IN('respuestas', 'pensamientos', 'libros');
```

**Referencia**

- [Operadores de comparación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in)

Comment: ¿No importando que en una de ellas tenga un while($filas2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2)) y en otra $filas1 = $resultado1->fetch_assoc();? ¿tendría que hacerlo con uno u otro?

Comment: La consulta será solo una y posterior ya con un while o un foreach iteras los resultados, no necesitas mas

Comment: Mil gracias por la respuesta, en este momento voy a probar.

Comment: No me muestra el campo 2 de pensamientos, me muestra el campo2 de respuestas 
SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM tabla WHERE identificador IN('respuestas', 'pensamientos', 'libros');

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que en tu pregunta añadas la estructura de la tabla y unos datos de prueba similares a los que posees para poder hacer pruebas y en caso necesario modificaciones

Comment: Listo ya agregue de que forma esta la tabla.

Comment: Pues con la estructura que pusiste en la pregunta hice un ejemplo en local y funciona, me trae todos los datos de la tabla cuyo id este entre alguno de los 3 listados

Comment: El resultado que me gustaría obtener es: x, y, z  ya que así hago la consulta en mi ejemplo. consulta1 pide campo1 de respuestas, consulta2 pide campo2 de pensamientos y consulta3 pide campo3 libros

Comment: Entonces tal vez agrupando, por qué de ahí en más no le veo más lógica a tu consulta

Comment: OK de cualquier forma mil gracias por la información

Comment: igual esperemos los aportes de otros usuarios de la comunidad @Abner igual alguen mas te propone la solución